# Autolink plugin prevents inserting new words after the autolink

Tags: lexicaljs, lexical-editor

I'm having a problem implementing the auto link plugin (copied from LexicalPlayground repo) in my Lexical Editor.

When I enter the link in my editor instance it properly identifies the autolink, but when I hit space I cannot enter a new word. The cursor remains on the link.

Here is my AutoLink plugin code with image attached below showing the TreeView with corresponding nodes.

**It appears the offset isn't updating according to the TreeView**
It just remains at offset: 1, as many times as hit the spacebar.

```
import {
  AutoLinkPlugin as LexicalAutoLinkPlugin,
  createLinkMatcherWithRegExp,
} from '@lexical/react/LexicalAutoLinkPlugin'

const URL_REGEX =
  /((https?:\/\/(www\.)?)|(www\.))[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&//=]*)/

export const MATCHERS = [
  createLinkMatcherWithRegExp(URL_REGEX, (text) => {
    return text.startsWith('http') ? text : `https://${text}`
  }),
]

export function AutoLinkPlugin(): JSX.Element {
  return <LexicalAutoLinkPlugin matchers={MATCHERS} />
}
```

Any ideas why?[image]

Comment: I got the same behavior, did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It was, in my case, an issue with `css`. try to check `.editor-paragraph`